# TextField JavaFX pegando o evento

Tags: java, javafx

Gostaria de saber qual o evento que ao sair do objeto `TextField` do `JavaFx`, altera um valor de um outro objeto.

```
if (textFieldC1.getText().equals("50")) {
    slider1.setValue(Double.valueOf(textFieldC1.getText()));
}
```

Comment: Tenta com focus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549296/how-perform-task-on-javafx-textfield-at-onfocus-and-outfocus

Comment: Não resolveu Jerfesson Assis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente dessa maneira:

```
textFieldC1.setOnAction( (ActionEvent e)-> {
 if(textFieldC1.getText().equals("50")) {
     slider1.setValue(Double.valueOf(textFieldC1.getText()))
 } });
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Deus lhe abençoe!